# Can Bazel let one rule see the output of another rule (cmake then make)

Tags: makefile, cmake, bazel

I need to run cmake to create Makefiles, then make to compile.
(Using ForeignCc for cmake and make).
The problem is that the make step doesn't see the Makefiles from cmake.
There are only 3 Makefiles. I've tested, and that's all I would need to copy over.
But is it possible to just let make run in the processed directory that cmake worked on?
Thanks

Comment: In the past `rules_foreign_cc` used to call `cmake`, then `make`. Currently the `cmake --build` is called. and you can customize it as you want. What is your problem, why you can not build your library using a single `cmake` bazel target?

Comment: I don't know. I can't tell what cmake commands it's executing. I can't see the cmake stdout/stderr. It a huge black box. I gave up and ran my own cmake commands. Here is what I have so far, but it's not finished yet, I need to deal with the cmake path - not requiring it to be already installed and available.

Comment: genrule(
  name = "cbor_cmake",
  srcs = glob(["**"]),
  outs = ["libcbor.a", "cbor.h", "cbor/arrays.h", "cbor/bytestrings.h",
          "cbor/callbacks.h", "cbor/cbor_export.h", "cbor/common.h", "cbor/configuration.h", "cbor/data.h",
          "cbor/encoding.h", "cbor/floats_ctrls.h", "cbor/ints.h", "cbor/maps.h",
          "cbor/serialization.h", "cbor/streaming.h", "cbor/strings.h", "cbor/tags.h"],

Comment: cmd = " && ".join([
    # Remember where output should go.
    "INITIAL_WD=`pwd`",
    # Build libcbor library.
    "cd `dirname $(location CMakeLists.txt)`",
    "cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCBOR_CUSTOM_ALLOC=ON .",
    "cmake --build .",
    # Export the .a and .h files for cbor rule, below.
    "test -f src/libcbor.a",
    "test -f src/cbor.h",
    "cp src/libcbor.a src/cbor.h $$INITIAL_WD/$(RULEDIR)",
    "cp src/cbor/*h cbor/configuration.h $$INITIAL_WD/$(RULEDIR)/cbor"]),
  visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)

Comment: cc_import(
  name = "cbor",
  hdrs = ["cbor.h", "cbor/arrays.h", "cbor/bytestrings.h",
          "cbor/callbacks.h", "cbor/cbor_export.h", "cbor/common.h", "cbor/configuration.h", "cbor/data.h",
          "cbor/encoding.h", "cbor/floats_ctrls.h", "cbor/ints.h", "cbor/maps.h",
          "cbor/serialization.h", "cbor/streaming.h", "cbor/strings.h", "cbor/tags.h"],
  static_library = "libcbor.a",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

Comment: I'll figure out a better way to post this when it's done...

Comment: You are mentioning a ForeingCc project, but you have pasted a code, which call cmake using a `genrule`. Please provide some minimal repository, which can be used to reproduce the issue